# Data table not being populated - google charts

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to plot a graph and table using google charts and some dynamically generated JSON.  I've altered the output to try and match the google requirements but I'm still struggling to get this to work.  I have spent countless hours trying to figure this out but I've finally hit a brick wall.  I've included an example of the generated JSON.

I get a blank space where the chart should be and a visible, titled table with no data in it (but roughly the correct number of lines).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Nation stats analyser</title>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'table']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAndTable);       

    function drawChartAndTable() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        dataType: "json",
        }).done(function (jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

            Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (row) {
                data.addRow([
                    row.Category
                    row.Value
                ]);
            });
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});

            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
            table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
        });
    }

    setTimeout(drawChartAndTable(), 100);


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
```

```
[{"Category":"Anarchy","Value":317},
{"Category":"Capitalizt","Value":108},{"Category":"New York Times 
Democracy","Value":918},{"Category":"Benevolent 
Dictatorship","Value":44},{"Category":"Inoffensive Centrist   
Democracy","Value":1993}]
```

Comment: What is the error does it shows in browser console?

Comment: No error is shown.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(data);`

Comment: Load `jquery.min.js` before `loader.js` and let me know the status.

Comment: It's now working thanks to the accepted answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
        jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
            data.addRow([
                row.Category,
                row.Value
            ]);
        });
```

Comment: Sadly didn't work.  That gives me a "display.php:28 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error for row.Value (although oddly not row.Category.)

Comment: comma `,` was missing after `Category`

Comment: I believe this was the change that fixed it.  Thanks.  Accepted the answer.